# Java - ExecutorService Cancelling Overhead

Tags: java, thread-safety, executorservice, cancellation

I am writing a program that generates images in response to user interaction (panning). For each image I create a task and submit this to a `ThreadPool`. To make the panning more responsive I create two versions of the image needed, one low resolution one and then a high resolution one. The high resolution image can take more than a second to calculate and if the user is panning a lot I do not want to bog down the processor with calculating old high res images. To manage this I have created an `UpdateHandler` (this is an inner class) in my program that is supposed to sort this out.

On occation some processes that should have been cancelled slip through. What am I doing wrong, why is this not thread safe? I am not great at multi-threading so any tips are welcome.

`Updatehandler`:

```
private class UpdateHandler {
    private boolean cancelled = false;
    private int number;
    private Future<WritableImage> future;
    private ChangeListener<Number> listener = new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
            if(newValue.intValue() > number) {
                cancel();                       
            }
        }               
    }; 

    private UpdateHandler() {
        number = numberOfUpdaters.get() + 1;
        numberOfUpdaters.set(number);
        numberOfUpdaters.addListener(listener); 
        if(number < numberOfUpdaters.get()) {//If the number was increased before the listener was applied.
            cancel();
        }

        updateLowResImage();

        int resolution = (int) rightPane.resolutionField.getValue();
        if(resolution > lowResolution && !isCancelled()) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    EnhancedCallable<WritableImage> task = getImageTask(resolution, resolution);
                    task.setDescription("Generating " + name);
                    future = threadPool.submit(task);
                    if(isCancelled()) {//If cancelled before construction but after check cancel again.
                        cancel();
                    }

                    try {
                        WritableImage image = future.get();
                        if(image != null) {
                            setImage(image);
                        }
                    } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException | CancellationException e) {
                        //Do nothing.
                    } finally {//When we are done cancel to make sure the listener is removed.
                        cancel();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Cancels the future or prevents it from starting. Can be called several times without problems.
     */
    private void cancel() {
        cancelled = true;
        try {
            if(!future.isDone() && !future.isCancelled()) {//If Future is still active.
                future.cancel(true);
            }

            if(future.isDone() || future.isCancelled()) {//If Future is not active anymore.
                numberOfUpdaters.removeListener(listener);
            }
        } catch(NullPointerException e) {//If the Future is not yet initialised.
            numberOfUpdaters.removeListener(listener);
        }
    }
    private boolean isCancelled() {
        return cancelled;
    }   
}
```

Comment: There are many errors related to java concurrency. The actual behaviour depends on the other code.

Comment: @SergeBogatyrev okay that is unfortunate. There is so much code surrounding this that I would think it is best if I do some further investigations of my own.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: At first I can suggest to check 2 points:
(1) image generation task should be cancel-friendly. Task cancellation should be supported internally.
(2) I suspect data race is possible in "numberOfUpdaters" implementation. At any case "set(get() + 1)" is not cool.